# Spring ldap : not granted any authorities

Tags: java, xml, spring, security, ldap

I am trying to remove constructor info from xml file. And these info will be loaded via System.getProperty.

The original code worked fine, like this:

```
    <bean id="authoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="initialDirContextFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="OU=AA,DC=US,DC=BB,DC=local"/>
        <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="CN"/>
        <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="OU=AA,DC=US,DC=BB,DC=local"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="initialDirContextFactory"/>
        <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="initialDirContextFactory" class="com.AA.BB.LdapConfig"/>
```

I modified the code. Now, ldap can't find any user: Authenticated false. Not granted any authorities.

```
<bean id="initialDirContextFactory" class="com.AA.BB.LdapConfig"/>
<bean id="authoritiesPopulator" class="com.AA.BB.AuthoritiesPopulator"/>
<bean id="userSearch" class="com.AA.BB.UserSearch"/>
public class UserSearch implements LdapUserSearch {
    public UserSearch() {
        this.searchBase="OU=AA,DC=US,DC=BB,DC=local";
        this.searchFilter="(sAMAccountName={0})"
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you !

update:

```
ldap structure
us.BB.local
AA(foler)
AAA(subfolder)
BBB(subfolder)
CCC(subfolder)
DDD(subfolder);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="initialDirContextFactory" class="com.AA.BB.LdapConfig"/>
<bean id="authoritiesPopulator" class="com.AA.BB.AuthoritiesPopulator"/>
<bean id="userSearch" class="com.AA.BB.UserSearch">        
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="initialDirContextFactory"/>
    <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
</bean>
// UserSearch copied from FilterBasedLdapUserSearch, just modified the constructor
public class UserSearch implements LdapUserSearch {
    public UserSearch(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
        this.contextSource = contextSource;
        this.searchBase="OU=AA,DC=US,DC=BB,DC=local";
        this.searchFilter="(sAMAccountName={0})"
    }
}
```

This issue has been fixed by above code.

But I still can't figure out why the previous method does not work. I suspect that LdapConfig bean is not injected appropriately, although three beans are instantiated successfully.